# How to backup the installed applications in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, backup

I want to format my laptop and reinstall ubuntu. But I dont want to redownload all the installed applications again. Is there any way that I can first backup the installed apps or find the backup deb files so that its easy to setup my linux for the next time ??

Comment: http://clonezilla.org/

Comment: Btw if you find any answer below useful, accept the answer by clicking on the grey tick just below the downvote button

Answer (score 3):

The most useful backup application I've seen is called `Aptik` - all you need is a backup directory, stored locally or in the cloud. `Aptik` will backup PPAs, downloaded packages, software selections, application settings and themes and icons. *Very* useful.

You can install it through the ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository –y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptik
```

[image]

Hope this sorts you out **:)**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30399/discussion-on-answer-by-devrobot-how-to-backup-the-installed-applications-in-ubu).